# Why is an equal sign after String in Ajax jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am gonna pass my HTML input value to PHP through jQuery Ajax. I got this code online but I don't understand in $.Ajax () why a new string (usearch) came inside data with an equal(=) sign next to it ("usearch=")? Why is the = sign? and why is the variable s concatenated to this string?
What does it mean-> 'usearch='+s ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#search').keyup(function(){

var s=$('#search').val();

$.ajax({
        url: 'getcustomer.php',
        data: 'usearch='+s,
        success: function(data){
            $('#cusName').html(data);    
        }
});
});    
});
```

Comment: It means that the data will be something like `search=foo`. It's a query parameter as in `domain.com?search=foo`

Comment: BTW, it's better to write `{usearch: s}`. If the search string contains special characters, `$.ajax` will encode them properly.